# Android 14 back Button closes flutter app instead of popping

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-go-router

I've been having a maddening issue with Flutter and GoRouter for a while now, When I press the phone's back button it either minimizes the app or closes it instead of popping to the previous page. It seems to only be an issue on Android 14 and pops perfectly on earlier Android versions

I'm Using PopScope to handle the pops
Like I said, Popping works fine in-app and also when using older Android versions but it's not working with v14 when pressing the Android's own back button
I'm currently experiencing this on my Samsung and also on an Android emulator using Android 14

I've seen similar posts but nothing exactly related to this issue

I humbly request the assistance of anybody who knows how to solve this please...And yes i have read the documentation

I've tried a bunch of changes in the GoRouter and even replaced PopScope with something else and asked on another form about it, I also looked into
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back
which didn't solve the issue either
Looked into similar issues on StackOverflow aswell

I don't think GoRouter's backButtonDispatcher is working well with Android 14

any thoughts?

My Router is setup as such

```
GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: LoginScreen.routeName,
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: LoginScreen.routeName,
      name: LoginScreen.title,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => MaterialPage<void>(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: const LoginScreen(),
      ),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: PinScreen.routeName,
      name: PinScreen.title,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => MaterialPage<void>(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: const PinScreen(),
      ),
    ),
```

```
And my main is setup like
```

```
 return MaterialApp.router(
      scaffoldMessengerKey: scaffoldMessengerKey,
      title: 'My APP',
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      locale: AppLocalizations.getStoredLocale(),
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en'),
        Locale('af'),
      ],
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light, useMaterial3: false),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark, useMaterial3: false),
      routerConfig: router,
    );
```

Comment: can you somehow verify that the button you press to go back indeed fires back-action? and not home-action.

Comment: You can try removing android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true" in your AndroidManifest if it is there

Comment: @rupinderjeet i realised that PopScope isnt being invoked at all,I'm directly working on GoRouter for pops

```[GoRouter] popping /page```

is the log I get

Comment: So from my previous comment...PopScope isnt used,Im calling the pop directly on the router ```router.pop``` which works fine,I even changed my emulator back to android 13 and the back button worked but closed the app on android 14 

so the issue is directly most likely on the GoRouter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the flutter version, in my project I updated the version and resolved

Comment: im currently on v3.16.4?

Comment: i update to v3.19.2 and solved this problem